# Make hypothesis test all values

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I'm looking for a way to make hypothesis do the following:

```py
@given(device=st.test_every_value_of(["cpu", "gpu"])
def test_a_thing(self, device):
  do_something_with_device(device)
```

But I haven't found a strategy like `st.test_every_value_of`.

What's a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there are two potential solutions.

The first is to use [`st.sampled_from`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.sampled_from):

```py
@given(device=st.sampled_from(["cpu", "gpu"]))
def test_a_thing(self, device):
  do_something_with_device(device)
```

`st.sampled_from` is not guaranteed to test all the values passed to it. However, Hypothesis, by default, generates 100 test cases from the specified strategies. If `st.sampled_from` contains >100 items or if it's used in conjunction with other strategies then it may not test all values; however, for smaller tests it may work fine.

The better solution is probably to use pytest's [parameterize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html):

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parameterize("device", ["cpu", "gpu"])
def test_a_thing(self, device):
  do_something_with_device(device)
```

If this is used in conjunction with hypothesis then hypothesis will run 100 tests for each instance generated by parameterize.